# GCR Builds fail

Tags: docker, google-container-registry, google-compute-engine

In the last week all of my builds with Google Cloud Registry fail with the following message after 1 minute of build time:

> Error response from daemon: No such container: b673590505f0d07c58c5d6413d46d522b4f17549ebe72c523230eff0f8772e6f
>
> Error: No such container: b673590505f0d07c58c5d6413d46d522b4f17549ebe72c523230eff0f8772e6f

seem like the build containers are dying?

Comment: Can you give me the build ID of the failed build? (it's a random number and cannot be used by anyone outside your project, so it's safe to share)

Comment: @JohnAsmuth I think i found the cause for something like: 042750ab-01d0-4dd6-ae14-f808dc0508a8.  I have 6 parallel builds and one of them builds openresty which failed.  It takes a bit of digging through the logs to realize this of course.  Perhaps if one build fails a more comprehensive build error message could be bubbled up?